# Make isearch commands search only at the beginning of words

Tags: isearch, words

How to make `C-s` (`isearch-forward`) and `C-r` (`isearch-backward`) search only for words that start with the argument passed to them, instead of searching for the argument even if it's in the middle of a word?

Comment: For 2) see section "Position of the Cursor after Searching" here https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IncrementalSearch

Comment: Please post two separate questions for your two separate question. As it stands now, the question is too broad and may be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You can either toggle word-search-mode by doing <kbd>M-s w</kbd> after starting isearch, or you can use start in word search mode directly using `isearch-forward-word`, also bound to <kbd>M-s w</kbd>.

Comment: I tried it first, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have an equivalent `isearch-backward-word`. And it only shows the first matched word, with no way (apparently) to go to the next match.

Comment: `isearch-backward-word` doesn't exist, but you can do `C-r M-s w`, or write it and choose your own binding. Once you're in word mode you can just use `C-s` or `C-r` to go to the next match.

Answer (score 2):

`word-search-mode` is the usual way to constrain your searches to words rather than letters, as @rpluim shows.

An alternative, more general approach is to use regular expression searches, `isearch-forward-regexp`, or `C-M-s`, and also the reverse `isearch-backward-regexp` and `C-M-r`. You can then use a regular expression to limit your search: `\bin` will match `in` when it occurs at the start of a word.

This is not as convenient as `word-search-mode`, but it is more flexible. For instance, you could find words ending with `er` with `er\b`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to do this

```
;; Use isearch-forward-word by default (treats a space as any whitespace or punctuation)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'isearch-forward-word)
;; This is the same as isearch-forward-word except with the first argument to
;; isesarch-mode set to nil to do reverse search
(defun isearch-backward-word (&optional not-word no-recursive-edit)
  "Do incremental search backward for a sequence of words.
With a prefix argument, do a regular string search instead.
Like ordinary incremental search except that your input is treated
as a sequence of words without regard to how the words are separated.
See the command `isearch-forward' for more information.
This command does not support character folding, and lax space matching
has no effect on it."
  (interactive "P\np")
  (isearch-mode nil nil nil (not no-recursive-edit) (null not-word)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-r") 'isearch-backward-word)
```

`isearch-backward-word` doesn't exist so I just copied the source of `isearch-forward-word` and changed the first argument of `isearch-mode` to `nil` to do reverse isearch.